# Why do I have to return Unit.INSTANCE in a void kotlin function, when called from Java, and not NULL?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, null

When having a function, for example:

```
fun doSomething(action:() -> Unit) {
   action.invoke()
}
```

if I call this from Java the code needs to be:

```
doSomething(() -> {
   //do something
   return Unit.INSTANCE
})
```

I have seen code instead using

```
doSomething(() -> {
   //do something
   return null
})
```

Does it affect sending `null` instead of `Unit.INSTANCE`? Do Kotlin perform more things by validating that UNIT instance is returned instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think most of the time it will not really matter whether `null` or `Unit.INSTANCE` is used. However as there is at least 1 case where such a `null` is not desirable, you should probably always use `Unit.INSTANCE` then.

One such made-up example where not returning `Unit.INSTANCE` will cause a problem is the following:

```
fun doSomething(action:() -> Unit) {
   action.invoke() logReturnTime("after action invocation")
}
infix fun Unit.logReturnTime(msg : String) { TODO("logging return time $msg") }
```

If you would call this and return `null` you would get an `IllegalArgumentException`, whereas the code would run without problem if you use `Unit.INSTANCE`.

That having said, I don't believe this is a good example, but it clearly shows, if anyone operates on that `Unit`, then it could fail, so you probably better always use `Unit.INSTANCE` and you are safe, regardless on what the receiver does with your function.

Answer (score 2):

Any method in Kotlin returns a value. "void" methods always return the one instance of the type `Unit` which is `Unit.INSTANCE`. You can obmit the return type unit in the declaration but implicitly it is added and the value is returned at the end of the method.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html

So when calling the Kotlin method from Java code, you need to fullfill the same contract and return something. If you return `null` is is a null reference to the type `Unit`. Just because it is better, to avoid null references, in case a caller would like to act on the result of your method, you should avoid returning `null` and return `Unit.INSTANCE` instead. Yes, this case is unlikely, but will cause the most annoying error.